# Cannor read properties of undefined (reading 'data' )

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I try to print data from a document from `firebase emulators` but when I start the `function` by accessing this url: `http://localhost:$port/$project/us-central1/MoveOldEvents-0` I get the following error:

```
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
i  functions: Beginning execution of "MoveOldEvents"
⚠  functions: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at processBackground (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:551:24)
    at invokeTrigger (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:641:19)
    at handleMessage (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:741:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

this is the function that I try to run:

```
exports.MoveOldEvents = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 1 minutes").timeZone("Europe/Bucharest").onRun(async (context) => {
  const eventsRef = admin.firestore().collection("collection").doc("test");
  const doc = await eventsRef.get();

  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
  } else {
    console.log('Data: ', doc.data());
  }
});
```

Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: Seems to me that `const doc` is `undefined`. So I believe that `await eventsRef.get()` is returning undefined. That's the function you need to check what is going on.

Comment: I've added data to the firestore emulator with the path collection/test but still got the same error

Comment: If you `console.log(doc)` before your if statement, it will probably be returning `undefined`. Can you confirm that?

Comment: still the same error, nothing has changed

Comment: A `console.log` will never fix any error, my idea was to help you to identify what's going on. Seems to me that the error might be happening inside the functions you're calling, and not in the code you have pasted. I'm sorry, but hard to help like this.

Comment: I know, I meant to say that it doesn't print `undefined`, or anything else beside that error

Comment: Can you try updating the firebase CLI using the following command. `npm install -g firebase-tools` ?